# Modeling Abandoned Cart on Orders or Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, bestpractice, order

I'd like to begin modeling abandoned carts inside our org. We can reliably push in data from the cart on our ecommerce platform at various stages throughout the checkout process, email the customer based on this data via Marketing Cloud, and perhaps clear the "cart" in Salesforce if the customer has not visited it recently.

We already use the Order to represent a completed purchase, and use Reduction Orders for returns.

My question is, what are the merits to using the Opportunity (and its native ability to represent stages) to model an abandoned cart, versus using an Order with a status of 'Draft'?

What strengths does the Opportunity have in representing this? What does the Order do better?  Can Trend Reporting be of any use in this scenario? Does the ease of having purchase information always on one object outweigh this?

Answer (score 1):

This question may be too opinion based and get closed. I'll give it a go, however.

Using Order seems more consistent. The situations you describe are not that different from each other. If you want to implement forecasting, you might find an appropriate weight for your draft orders that improves your predictive power. Also if you recover and complete the sale, you can just change the status, instead of coming up with a conversion process. You are going to have the same data points, including child and parent records, and implementing polymorphic lookups isn't even possible.

TL;DR it seems likely implementing Opportunities is going to lead to a lot of extra effort without a clear win.